# Prevent Maruku from posting so many log warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, markdown, maruku

I use Maruku in Rails simply to convert a Markdown file to HTML so I can use it with Nokogiri. (Maybe there's a better solution for that?) That works fine, but I get lots and lots of "Maruku tells you" messages in the log:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________
| Maruku tells you:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Could not find ref_id = "FIX" for md_link("FIX", nil)
| Available refs are []
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

That's really confusing and not needed here. Is there a way to silence Maruku so it only warns in the log if there's a real error?

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri question, as Nokogiri isn't involved in the code you didn't show us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try [`rdiscount`](https://github.com/davidfstr/rdiscount) gem?

I find Maruku too verbose with errors and do not want to have to ignore all error.

Comment: Thank you, that gem seems to be much better suited for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/bhollis/maruku/blob/master/lib/maruku/errors.rb) and [documentation](https://github.com/bhollis/maruku), it looks like you can set `:on_error` to `:ignore` :

```
Maruku.new(string, :on_error => :ignore)
```

It might also silence "real errors", though.

Comment: Thank you! This solution feels bad, but I didn't find anything better with Maruku. Seems it's time to use something a bit newer.